# How to create/find right ID in multiple Form elements of same type $ajax function with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible part of my jQuery Mobile page that are generated from PHP output from a MS Sql databas and content render as I like it to so that part is ok.

in each section I create a form with 3 buttons and they are supposed to have unique Id:s.
All forms are also created to have a unique id created in runtime.

actions.php (renders out my elements into mobilepage i  a DIV)

```
 $counter=0; reset counter for ID:s
 while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)){

// data output from Db to make like 10 collapsible with different data
    $html = "";
    $html = "<div data-role='collapsible-set' data-mini='true'>";
        $html.="<div data-role='collapsible' data-mini='true'>";
        $html.="<h3><span style=float:left;><img src='../_pic/$image' alt='$imageText' /> ".substr($Time,0,16)."&nbsp;&nbsp;$Area</span><span style='float:right;' class='ui-btn-up-c  ui-btn-corner-all' cnt>&nbsp;$data&nbsp;</span></h3>";
        $html.="<p>ID:&nbsp;$ID&nbsp;$Id&nbsp;&nbsp;$Status<br />$Status&nbsp;&nbsp;$Description)</p>";

        $html.="<form method='post' action=''>";
        $html.="<button value='action1' id='action1$counter' data-mini='true'      type='Submit'>Take Action1</button>";
           $html.="<button value='action2' id='action2$counter' data-mini='true' type='Submit'>Take Action1</button>";
           $html.="<button value='action3' id='action3$counter' data-mini='true' type='Submit'>Take Action1</button>";
        $html.="<input type='hidden' id='id$counter' name='id' value='$dataName' />";
        $html.="</form>";

        $html.="</div>";
     $html.="</div>";
     echo utf8_encode($html);
     $counter++;  //upcount to make Id:s unique 
} //end While
```

Then I have this function that listens for a button that submit:

```
$(':submit').live('click', function() { 
  var button = $(this).val();
        if (button == 'action1') { 
             $.ajax({ 
                url: '../_php/Functions.php', 
                data: 'button=' + $(this).val()+'&id='+$('#id').val(),  
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                },
                error: function (request,error) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });    
        }
    return false;
  });
```

I cant seem to get another id than the first one since i need to make all ID:s unique in my forms and all I do now is to check: `&id='+$('#id').val()`. what I would like to have done is to link the button pressed-id number to my hidden field id-number so i get the right data out from it. As of now I only get the first form:s id evaluated...

If someone could point me in the right direction how to make that happen i´d be greatful.

functions.php (a switch statement is pre-testing for submit:ed action

```
function actions1(){    
try {
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            do stuff with 'id'
    }else{
            do other stuff with 'id'
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
   show error
}
}
```

If some part is unclear or if you feel I missed posting somepart - let me know. /thanks

Answer (score 0):

Within event handlers `this` referes to the element

```
$(':submit').live('click', function(){
  var id= this.id;
  var button = $(this).val();
   /* traverse within form to set hidden input, no need to worry about using ID's for them*/
   $(this).closest('form').find('input[name=id]').val(id);
  /* then in ajax */
   data: 'button=' +button+'&id='+id,  

})
```

Not full code....I left some of your code out for simplicity

Comment: Hi agian. well it works but its not the ID from the button i need, probably my bad explanation. Its the value of the hidden input in the same form that the button was pushed that i need. .="<input type='hidden' id='id$counter' name='id' value='$dataName' />"; the value='$dataName' is the part that i want to attach as an argument for my .php-file.

Comment: `$(this).closest('form').find('input[name=id]').attr('id')` will return ID. Have no idea what you mean by attachments

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .attr() function to get an id or any other attribute value of an element.

```
 $(':submit').live('click', function() { 
      var button = $(this).val();
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
            if (button == 'action1') { 
                 $.ajax({ 
                    url: '../_php/Functions.php', 
                    data: 'button=' + $(this).val()+'&id='+ id,  
                    async: true,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                    },
                    error: function (request,error) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });    
            }
        return false;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to go by attributes name of my hidden input.

```
var id = $(this).closest("form").find(':hidden').val();
```